# Airflow BigQueryInsertJobOperator configuration

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow

I'm having some issue converting from the deprecated `BigQueryOperator` to `BigQueryInsertJobOperator`. I have the below task:

```
bq_extract = BigQueryInsertJobOperator(
    dag="big_query_task,
    task_id='bq_query',
    gcp_conn_id='google_cloud_default',
    params={'data': Utils().querycontext},
    configuration={
        "query": {"query": "{% include 'sql/bigquery.sql' %}", "useLegacySql": False,
                  "writeDisposition": "WRITE_TRUNCATE", "destinationTable": {"datasetId": bq_dataset}}
    })
```

this line in my bigquery_extract.sql query is throwing the error:

```
{% for field in data.bq_fields %}
```

I want to use `'data'` from params, which is calling a method, this method is reading from a .json file:

```
class Utils():
    bucket = Variable.get('s3_bucket')
    _qcontext = None

    @property
    def querycontext(self):
        if self._qcontext is None:
            self.load_querycontext()

        return self._qcontext

    def load_querycontext(self):
        with open(path.join(conf.get("core", "dags"), 'traffic/bq_query.json')) as f:
            self._qcontext = json.load(f)
```

the `bq_query.json` is this format, and I need to use the nested `bq_fields` list values:

```
{
"bq_fields": [
    { "name": "CONCAT(ID, '-', CAST(ID AS STRING), "alias": "new_id" },
    { "name": "TIMESTAMP(CAST(visitStartTime * 1000 AS INT64)", "alias": "new_timestamp" },
    { "name": "TO_JSON_STRING(hits.experiment)", "alias": "hit_experiment" }]
}
```

this file has a list which I want to use in the above mentioned query line, but its throwing this error:

> jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'data' is undefined

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with your code.

First "params" is not a supported field in BigQueryInsertJobOperator. See this post where I post how to pass params to sql file when using BigQueryInsertJobOperator. [How do you pass variables with BigQueryInsertJobOperator in Airflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68027380/how-do-you-pass-variables-with-bigqueryinsertjoboperator-in-airflow)

Second, if you happen to get an error that your file cannot be found, make sure you set the full path of your file. I have had to do this when migrating from local testing to the cloud, even though file is in same directory. You can set the path in the dag config with example below(replace path with your path):

```
 with DAG(
    ...
    template_searchpath = '/opt/airflow/dags',
    ...
    
) as dag:
```