# How do you pass variables with BigQueryInsertJobOperator in Airflow

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow

I am trying to use BigQueryInsertJobOperator for a query of Google BigQuery. I am trying to pass variable names into a sql file, but I am getting an error. The error is slightly different based on what I type in the sql file, but it doesn't recognize the variable.

DAG

```
TABLE_1 = "my_table"

with DAG(
    dag_id,
    schedule_interval='@daily',
    start_date= days_ago(1),
    template_searchpath = '/mypath/sql/',
    catchup = False,
   
    
) as dag:

    query_one = BigQueryInsertJobOperator(
        task_id='query_test',
        configuration={
            "query":{
                "query": "{% include 'big_insert_job_test.sql' %}",
                "defaultDataset":{
                    "datasetId":"my_dataset_id",
                    "projectId":"my_project_id"
                },
    
                "queryParameters": [
                    {
                    "name": "TABLE_1",
                    "parameterType": {
                        "type": "STRING",
                    },
                    "parameterValue": {"value":TABLE_1}
                    }
                ]   
    
                            
            }
        }
```

SQL File

```
SELECT * FROM @TABLE_1
```

According to the google docs I can pass a variable as a "@" or a "?".
I have tried sending the variables many different ways:

```
SELECT * FROM {{params.TABLE_1}}. // This is how it works with BigQueryExecuteQueryOperator, 
but that is deprecated so trying to use the BigQueryInsertJobOperator

SELECT * FROM `TABLE_1` // just an example, 
I have tried every combo of "", '', {}, etc
```

Comment: I built this operator  Can you share rendered value for `configuration` argument? Do I correctly understand that the templating of query is BigQuery feature not Airflow? Also thanks to new interface of operator you can test this configuration using [try this](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/insert) from Google docs.

Comment: When using BigQueryExecuteQueryOperator, Airflow would pass the variables to the sql statement before sending it to Bigquery.  With the now preferred BigQueryInsertJobOperator, Airflow does not pass the variables first. Thats a good idea to try and use Bigquery directly, as I am not sure if the Error is from Airflow or Bigquery. One big issue I have is I have a hard time understanding the google docs, so I don't even know I am passing the "configuration", which is just a bigquery object and not dictated by airflow.

Answer (score 2):

Parameters can be passed from your DAG to a separate sql file by using the user_defined_macros={"varname": var1, "varname2": var2}. So pass your variables in the top portion of the DAG for general config, and it will be available in your operators if you call a file.

```
from airflow import models
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.bigquery import BigQueryInsertJobOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

PROJECT_ID = os.environ.get("GCP_PROJECT_ID", "example-project")
DATASET_NAME = os.environ.get("GCP_BIGQUERY_DATASET_NAME", "test_dataset")

TABLE_1 = "table1"
dag_id = "dag1"

with models.DAG(
    dag_id,
    schedule_interval=None,  # Override to match your needs
    start_date=days_ago(1),
    tags=["example"],
    user_defined_macros={"DATASET": DATASET_NAME, "TABLE": TABLE_1},
) as dag:

    select_query_job = BigQueryInsertJobOperator(
        task_id="select_query_job",
        configuration={
            "query": {
                "query": "{% include 'example_bigquery_query.sql' %}",
                "useLegacySql": False,
            }
        },
    )
```

In your sql file, inclose the variable with double brackets.

```
SELECT * FROM {{ DATASET }}.{{ TABLE }}
```

For reference here are the examples from airflow's github

example dag file:
https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/d87ab6d3a54cb6937cfa1771c901f34dda6a2f65/airflow/providers/google/cloud/example_dags/example_bigquery_queries.py

example sql file:
https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/d87ab6d3a54cb6937cfa1771c901f34dda6a2f65/airflow/providers/google/cloud/example_dags/example_bigquery_query.sql

Comment: When i try this, i get sometimes a jinja TemplateNotFound error. Do you know how to work around this?

Comment: @mikrohelen Have you tried passing the `template_searchpath` keyword argument to your DAG contructor?

Comment: Is there a way to parametise the sql file name e.g. example_bigquery_query.sql in your code?  I want to pass in the sql filename into the function

Answer (score 2):

Adding this for those who might come here looking for a solution. This is a working example that I came up with. You can add additional parameters in the `params` dict.

```
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.bigquery import BigQueryInsertJobOperator
from airflow import models
from airflow.utils.dates import datetime, timedelta


default_args = {
    'depends_on_past': False,
    # 
    'location': location_as_a_string,
    'project_id': project_id,
    'gcp_conn_id': 'google_cloud_default'
}

with models.DAG(
    dag_id,
    default_args=default_args,
    catchup=False,
    description='Testing Operator',
    schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1)
) as dag:

    select_query_job = BigQueryInsertJobOperator(
        task_id="select_query_job",
        configuration={
            "query": {
                "query": "{% include 'bq_example_query_1.sql' %}",
                "useLegacySql": False,
                "destinationTable": table_name,
                "write_disposition": "WRITE_TRUNCATE"
            }
        },
        params={'table_name':  'project.dataset.table_name'}
    )
```

`bq_example_query_1.sql`

```
SELECT * FROM {{ params.table_name }}
```

Comment: For this part - {% include 'bq_example_query_1.sql' %} Where shall I keep my .sql file and how to specify the path ?

Comment: Keep `.sql` files in the dags folder. You can create a folder for all your `.sql` files within the dags folder and do something like this `{% include 'sql_files_folder_in_dags_folder/bq_example_query_1.sql' %}`

Comment: Is there a way to parametise the .sql filename?  e.g bq_example_query_1.sql

Comment: @MarkeD, since it is a string, I believe you can use f-strings to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the answer.
You should put 'parameterMode':'NAMED' in your 'query' item.

Referring to your source code,

```
query_one = BigQueryInsertJobOperator(
        task_id='query_test',
        configuration={
            "query":{
                "query": "{% include 'big_insert_job_test.sql' %}",
                "defaultDataset":{
                    "datasetId":"my_dataset_id",
                    "projectId":"my_project_id"
                },
                "queryParameters": [
                    {
                    "name": "TABLE_1",
                    "parameterType": {
                        "type": "STRING",
                    },
                    "parameterValue": {"value":TABLE_1}
                    }
                ],
                "parameterMode": "NAMED", # REQUIRED
            }
        }
```

parameterValue can have 'POSITIONAL' or 'NAMED'

You can check POSITIONAL reference here
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-query-params-positional
POSITIONAL will replace '?' to the variables you set in order

You can check NAMED reference here
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries
NAMED will replace '@variable' to the variable you set with 'name'

I hope it would be helpful

Comment: This only works for parameters in the WHERE clause e.g. `WHERE myval = @myval` - it does not work for general text substitution in a query e.g. for table names `SELECT * FROM @some_table` will not work.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when updating the deprecated `BigQueryExecuteQueryOperator` to  `BigQueryInsertJobOperator`. The following solution worked for me.

```
from airflow import models
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.bigquery import BigQueryInsertJobOperator

project_id = os.environ.get("GCP_PROJECT_ID", "example-project")
dataset_id = os.environ.get("GCP_BIGQUERY_DATASET_NAME", "test_dataset")

table_id = "table1"
dag_id = "dag1"

def read_sql(path):
    with open(path, "r") as file:
        sql_string = file.read()
    return sql_string

with models.DAG(
    dag_id,
    schedule_interval=None,  # Override to match your needs
    tags=["example"],
) as dag:

    select_query_job = BigQueryInsertJobOperator(
        task_id="select_query_job",
        configuration={
            "query": {
                "query": read_sql(f"{sql_path}/sample.sql").format(project_id=project_id,
                                                                            dataset_id=dataset_id),
           "destinationTable": {
                'projectId': project_id,
                'datasetId': dataset_id,
                'tableId': table_id
            },
           "useLegacySql": False,
           "writeDisposition": "WRITE_TRUNCATE",
            }
        },
    )
```

sample.sql:

```
SELECT * FROM `{project_id}.{dataset_id}.{table_id}`
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who need an answer for something like this and haven't obtained it yet.

The `BigQueryInsertJobOperator` has the `configuration` parameter, which allows you to create variables using `queryParameters`. The important thing here is that you cannot pass table names through this option, as it is designed to provide parameters for queries and prevent SQL injection.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries

So, you can use `params` parameter to make the table name a variable that you can controll from your dag.

```
select_query_job = BigQueryInsertJobOperator(
    task_id="select_query_job",
    configuration={
        "query": {
            "query": "{% include 'example_bigquery_query.sql' %}",
            "useLegacySql": False
        }
    },
    params = {"DATASET": "dataset_name", "TABLE": "table_name"}
)
```

And your query file should look like:

```
SELECT * FROM {{params["DATASET"]}}.{{params["TABLE"]}}
```